# In Ansible, Is there a way to use loop_controls index_var in loops range function

Tags: ansible

I need a task that will copy configuration templates to some amount of nodes.

If the number of configs > number of nodes I will have to reuse nodes.

The following python code will explain my problem.

```py
m = 16
nodes = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
    
ms = list(range(m))
    
    
def gen(m, nodes):
    for num, node in enumerate(nodes):
        print(f"{node}, num: {num}")
        for i in (ms[num::len(nodes)]):
            print(f"server{i+1}.conf")
    
    
gen(m, nodes)
```

Witch means that template should be written to the correct host in the following order:

```
server1.conf should be written on node1
server2.conf should be written on node2
server3.conf should be written on node3
server4.conf should be written on node1 # restarting from node 1 here
...
server15.conf should be written on node3
server16.conf should be written on node1 #
```

Is this possible in a task or should I just write an external library?

I have tried the following

```yaml
---
- name: test
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    conf:
      m: 6
  tasks:
    - name: loop debug
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} - {{ my_idx }}"
      loop: "{{ range(my_idx, conf.m, 2) }}" # not possible to use my_idx here
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
```

minor update, removed conf.k which is not needed in the example

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. A "loop" (in quotes because this not how this term is usualy used) at play level goes other each target in the pattern declared in the `hosts` stanza (i.e. `all` in your example). A `loop` on a task will iterate other each element in the loop for each target host. You might be able to acheive your requirement by using `set_fact` to create a list of templates for each host then loop on that list on each host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playbook below does the job

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    nodes: [node1, node2, node3]
    conf:
      m: 16
      k: "{{ nodes|length }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "server{{ item|int + 1 }}.conf should go to {{ nodes[_node|int] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(conf.m)|list }}"
      vars:
        _node: "{{ item|int % conf.k|int }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: server1.conf should go to node1
  msg: server2.conf should go to node2
  msg: server3.conf should go to node3
  msg: server4.conf should go to node1
  ...
  msg: server15.conf should go to node3
  msg: server16.conf should go to node1
```

---

Q: *"**Write template files to the correct host**"*

A: Create a dictionary first, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: node1,node2,node3
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    nodes: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
    conf:
      m: 16
      k: "{{ nodes|length }}"
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        node_confs: "{{ node_confs|default({})|combine({item: _batch}) }}"
      loop: "{{ nodes }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      vars:
        _confs: "{{ range(1, conf.m|int + 1)|list }}"
        _batch: "{{ _confs[ansible_loop.index0|int:]|
                    batch(conf.k|int)|
                    map('first')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

<sup>Update: The evaluation of *_batch* can be simplified</sup>

```yaml
        _batch: "{{ _confs[ansible_loop.index0|int::conf.k|int] }}"
```

---

gives the dictionary

```yaml
  node_confs:
    node1:
    - 1
    - 4
    - 7
    - 10
    - 13
    - 16
    node2:
    - 2
    - 5
    - 8
    - 11
    - 14
    node3:
    - 3
    - 6
    - 9
    - 12
    - 15
```

Then use this dictionary to loop the config to the hosts, .e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy server{{ item }}.conf to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      loop: "{{ node_confs[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Copy server2.conf to node2
  msg: Copy server1.conf to node1
  msg: Copy server5.conf to node2
  msg: Copy server4.conf to node1
  msg: Copy server8.conf to node2
  msg: Copy server11.conf to node2
  msg: Copy server7.conf to node1
  msg: Copy server14.conf to node2
  msg: Copy server10.conf to node1
  msg: Copy server13.conf to node1
  msg: Copy server16.conf to node1
  msg: Copy server3.conf to node3
  msg: Copy server6.conf to node3
  msg: Copy server9.conf to node3
  msg: Copy server12.conf to node3
  msg: Copy server15.conf to node3
```

Comment: This is almost correct it looks like. Only thing is i need to write template files to the correct host. I'm not sure how to write server1.conf, server4.conf... and so on to node1 and server2.conf, server5.conf.. and so on to node2.

Comment: Create a dictionary with the structure. Then the flow is trivial.

Comment: Can't thank you enough for taking your time, Vladimir! <3 It finally works!